# csv.reader misses first line

Tags: python, csv

I am using `csv.reader` in python to read a csv file into a dictionary. The first column of the csv is a date (in one of 2 possible formats) which is read in as a datetime object and becomes the key of the `dict`, and I also read columns 3 and 4:

```
import datetime as dt
import csv
with open(fileInput,'r') as inFile:
    csv_in = csv.reader(inFile)
    try:
        dictData = {(dt.datetime.strptime(rows[0], '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')): [rows[3], rows[4]]
                        for rows in csv_in}
    except:
        dictData = {(dt.datetime.strptime(rows[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')): [rows[3], rows[4]]
                        for rows in csv_in}
```

It works, except that the first date in the file (`1/7/2012 00:00`) doesn't appear in the dictionary. Do I need to tell `csv.reader` that the first row is not a header row and if so, how?

Comment: The code you wrote should work with that format (1/7/2012 00:00) and read the first line. I did a quick test and it read all lines. However, if the `try` and `except` were reversed, you would miss the first line, so your approach is not sound. If I were you, I would detect the date format and then seek the beginning of the file (like the Sniffer example in the docs). That would also avoid your try/except, because you'd know the format beforehand. You could still `try` just to catch any errors in format.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, most of the inputs are in the format YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss so I will convert all to this format and just read the one format. But why does the try: ... except: make it miss a row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run your `try`, `except` statement, it is easy to believe that python will first `try` something, and if that fails, revert your environment back to the state it was in before the `try` statement was executed. It does not do this. As such, you have to be aware of unintended side effects that might occur from a failed `try` attempt.

What is happening in your case is that the dictionary comprehension calls `next(...)` on your `csv.reader()` object (`csv_in`), which returns the first line in the csv file. You have now used up the first item from the `csv.reader()` iterator. Remember, Python won't revert to a previous state if the `try` block fails.

An exception is then raised, I'm presuming when the date is in the wrong format. When the `except` block then takes over, and calls `next(...)` on your `csv_in` object, you then get the second item in the iterator. The first has already been used.

A simple change to get around this is to make a copy of the csv iterator object.

```
import datetime as dt
import csv
from copy import copy
with open(fileInput,'r') as inFile:
    csv_in = csv.reader(inFile)
    try:
        dictData = {(dt.datetime.strptime(rows[0],'%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')):
                      [rows[3],rows[4]] for rows in copy(csv_in)}
    except ValueError:
        dictData = {(dt.datetime.strptime(rows[0],'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')):
                      [rows[3],rows[4]] for rows in copy(csv_in)}
```

Finally, I would recommend against catching a generic `Exception`. I think you would be wanting to catch a `ValueError`.

Comment: Thank you... I'm new to Python and had exactly that misunderstanding of 'try' and 'except'.  Now much clearer